# What is the difference between ShardedJedis and JedisCluster

Tags: java, redis, jedis

So I have 2 different approaches where I can use Redis cluster in Jedis:

**Method 1**
Link [here](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/wiki/AdvancedUsage)

```
    List<JedisShardInfo> shards = new ArrayList<JedisShardInfo>();

    JedisShardInfo si = null;

    si = new JedisShardInfo("10.7.2.242", 7003);
    shards.add(si);
    si = new JedisShardInfo("10.7.2.242", 7004);
    shards.add(si);
    si = new JedisShardInfo("10.7.2.242", 7005);
    shards.add(si);

    ShardedJedis jedis = new ShardedJedis(shards);

    jedis.set("foo_first", "foo");
```

**Method 2**
Link [here](https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis)

```
    Set<HostAndPort> jedisClusterNodes = new HashSet<HostAndPort>();
        jedisClusterNodes.add(new HostAndPort("10.7.2.242", 7003));
        jedisClusterNodes.add(new HostAndPort("10.7.2.242", 7004));
        jedisClusterNodes.add(new HostAndPort("10.7.2.242", 7005));
    System.out.println("cluster node set initialised");
    JedisCluster jc = new JedisCluster(jedisClusterNodes);
        jc.set("foo_first", "bar");
    String value = jc.get("foo_first");
    System.out.println(value);
```

Now I have a doubt why these 2 different approaches are there, and what is the basic difference between them?

Comment: @xetorthio Please shed some light

Answer (score 1):

ShardedJedis create shards logically, so it doesn't support H/A (failover), and re-distribute keys (because key distribution is based on algorithm and we can't change on the fly).

It was introduced while Redis doesn't care about cluster feature, and currently most of works you can do with ShardedJedis are done with RedisCluster (JedisCluster).

One big difference is node failure. ShardedJedis doesn't care about H/A so  failure of one node doesn't incur failure of whole cluster. (but you can't access keys within crashed node) But Redis Cluster treats situation to CLUSTERDOWN, so you should prepare slave nodes so that Redis Cluster can trigger failover.

Answer (score 0):

Sharding allow you to distribute your data in differents Nodes (Redis instances without ), now you can use Clustering to have access and distribute your data transparently.

Comment: How it is possible to distribute the data in Sharding. If you see the call of ShardedJedis we never tell to which shard put the data in to.
So its not the case

Comment: the mechanisme of distrbution (data) is implemented by a technique called "consistent hashing" that tell you for a key X will be inserted in node 2 for example. to force keys to go to a certain node you can see https://github.com/xetorthio/jedis/wiki/AdvancedUsage  "Force certain keys to go to the same shard" section.

Comment: the mechanism that i tell you is transparent for both Shareding and Clustering mode.